# Linux mint needed to boot in compatibility mode, but after install it does not boot!

Tags: linux, linux-mint, boot, drivers, hardware-compatibility

Linux mint needed to boot in compatibility mode, but after install it does not boot!

Explained:

1. i booted from the cd
2. it failed so i did it in compatibility mode
3. i successfully installed mint
4. it does not boot from the disk (it displays a few glitchy lines of random colors and halts)

Comment: No, linux mint is supposed to be very easy for beginners!

Comment: When you say compatibility mode you mean "fail-safe" mode?

Comment: i selected "Start in compatibility mode" on the dvd boot

Comment: why must linux mint be retarded x.x

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: Since Linux mint doesn't seem to have a fallback the easiest thing I can tell you is to try hold shift then power your system on. You should get a boot menu from GRUB. Press E and look for the linux line. Go to the end of that line and type nomodeset before the -- at the end of the line. Then press what ever key it says to boot. It'll tell you. It's probably F10.

Comment: That indicates the early boot drivers in Linux Mint are not working with your GPU. It could be as simple as you need to update your system or it could mean that Linux Mint is not up to date with drivers or it could mean you have a very new GPU.

Comment: Actually i have a 2010 GPU from a laptop (not nvidia just intel)

Answer (score 0):

you must disable apci from grub
boot from compatibility mode one more time then
sudo update-grub
then add line
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="noacpi"